# Get the text of a link within a table cell

Tags: cucumber, page-object-gem

I have a table similar to this one:

```
<table id="space-list" class="aui list-container">
    <tr class="space-list-item" data-spacekey="BLANKSPACEEXAMPLE">
        <td class="entity-attribute space-name">
            <a title="Blank Space Example" href="https://q-leap.atlassian.net/wiki/display/BLANKSPACEEXAMPLE/Blank+Space+Example+Home">
                Blank Space Example
            </a>
        </td>
        <td class="entity-attribute space-desc">
            <span>
                An example of a "Knowledge Base" type space, freely editable, accessible to everyone, may be deleted at any time.
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My PageObject code looks like this

```
class Space < PageObject::Elements::TableRow
  def name
    cell_element(index: 0).link_element(href: /q-leap/).text
  end

  def description
    cell_element(index: 1).text
  end
end
PageObject.register_widget :space, Space, :tr

class SpaceDirectoryPage
  include PageObject

  spaces(:space) do
    table_element(:id => 'space-list')
        .group_elements(:tag_name => 'tr')[1..-1]
  end
end
```

And now I am iterating over all the rows in the table to get the content of each cell:

```
while true
  on(SpaceDirectoryPage).space_elements.each_with_index do |space|
    puts space.name
    puts space.description
  end
end
```

Which is working fine for the description, but I have no clue how to access the text of the link within the first column; tried 100s of things, nothing worked.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you saying that `cell_element(index: 0).link_element(href: /q-leap/).text` does not work? It seems to be doing what you want.

Comment: It just returns an empty string.